# Why does branching leads to lower surface area?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know that lower surface area means lower interactive forces between molecules and hence lower boiling point. But the statement that branching leads to more compact molecules with lower surface area, I just cannot understand it. Can someone help me with a visual or any otehr kind of explanation?

Comment: If you have a lump of, I don't know, plasticine, and you want to minimise its surface area, what do you do? You roll it into a sphere, right? Now which looks more like a sphere: neopentane, or *n*-pentane?

Comment: @orthocresol Cannot I assume it as a square like surface area, where as n pentane is linear. Why does it roll into a sphere?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan Square is a 2D structure.The compact one is more spherical.Branching causes a molecule to become compact.

Comment: @ZOZ  I mean why they tend to get more compact? Why not more open and having more surface area as possible? Obviously square is 2-D structure, by it I mean being more open anyways...

Comment: In math the isoperimetric problem is to determine a plane figure of the largest possible area whose boundary has a given length. That is a circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality Likewise the 3D figure that has the greatest volume for a given surface area is the sphere. Look at models for neopentane https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neopentane and n-pentane https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentane

Comment: Say take a string.First extend it completely.Next,cut it into 4 parts and arrange it to make a neopentane like structure.Which is more compact and spherical?

Comment: @ZOZ, duh... I completely agree sphere is more compact. I say why a molecule makes itself more compact.

Comment: @MaxW, I don't get what you are proving. if surface area is fixed, then the story will end there only? Surface area is decreasing as molecule is becoming more compact.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan Branching makes a molecule compact.Therby a lower surface area.

Comment: @ZOZ sorry for making this so long a discussion, but do molecule have a general tendency to get as compact as possible?

Comment: Not necessarily.In small molecules with $\ce{sp3}$ centres continously free rotation occurs.However in very large molecules folding occurs to reduce surface area as you said.

Comment: @ZOZ Okay, but I still don't get why a compact structure is preferred.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan I hope you heard about Van Der Waal's attractive forces?That's what causes folding in large molecules.Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force . You might have read the NCERT textbooks which describe them well...

Comment: Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iYKajMsYPY ...explains it well...

Comment: @ZOZ yeah I am currently reading the NCERT textbook. It has only mentioned Van Der Waal's attractive forces on intermolecular, not intramolecular level. That's why I was confused. Thanks.